# How to delete oldest record in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

For eg: In a day I loaded 10 records in the table and I want first three newest records in a table and every other record should be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just design it like

```
CREATE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace_name.table_name (
  key text,
  year_month_day text,
  time timeuuid,
  record blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key, year_month_day), time)  
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

At end of day

```
SELECT * FROM keyspace_name.table_name LIMIT 3;`
```

then to delete the rest do

```
DELETE FROM keyspace_name.table_name WHERE key = 'something' AND year_month_day = '2017-05-05' AND time > lasttimefromselect`
```

**Alternatively** If you would rather do work on the insert and not require having a job to go back and clear it up... keep in mind this is slower but if only doing 10 there wont be any contention. You can just have a running counter and mod it by 3 to over write the oldest as it goes over 3. Then there will be no deletes necessary.

```
CREATE IF NOT EXISTS keyspace_name.table_name (
  key text,
  ymd text,
  offset int STATIC,
  bucket int, 
  record blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key, ymd), bucket)  
) WITH COMPACTION = { 'class' :  'LeveledCompactionStrategy'  };
```

Then do a read and CAS update

```
SELECT * FROM  keyspace_name.table_name WHERE key='key' AND ymd='yyyy-mm-dd';

BEGIN BATCH
  UPDATE table_name SET offset = [retrieved_offset+1] WHERE key = key AND ymd = 'yyyy-mm-dd' IF offset = [retrieved_offset];
  UPDATE table_name SET bucket=[retrieved_offset%3], record=[...] WHERE key = key AND ymd = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
APPLY BATCH;
```

and just put it in loop until `applied` is true.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your information.I will make the question clear.For Eg:There are n number of records are loading and I want to make a job scheduler and that should keep the first 5 newest or n th newest records in the table and every other records should be deleted

Comment: Thank you Chris for your information.I will make the question clear.For Eg:There are n number of records are loading and I want to make a job scheduler and that should keep the first 5 newest or first n th newest records in the table and every other records should be deleted? @Chris Lohfink

Comment: The two solutions above should do that. If you are reading all the data but just want to keep the top N then the first solution would probably make most sense since your reading it anyway. It would create a single range tombstone that deletes all the data older than the Nth.

Comment: Yes thank you but 'time > lasttimefromselect' here time is cluster key and Cassandra can't accept the > symbol.Do you know any alternative? @Chris Lohfink.

Comment: use  `maxTimeuuid(lasttimefromselect)`, you can use > but it has to be of timeuuid type